# Socket.IO doesn't connect in chrome extension but on node, postman and normal webpage console does

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, socket.io

This is my `background.js`:

```
import { io } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@4.7.1/+esm";


function connect(roomId) {
  ws = io(URL);

  ws.on("error", console.error);
  ws.on("connect", () => {
    log("Connected to server");
    ws.emit("join", roomId);
  });
}

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
  if (message.event === "joinRoom") {
    connect(message.roomId);
  }
});
```

My `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "YouTube Watch Together",
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "description": "Toby's pathetic attempt at a YouTube Watch Together extension",
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/logo.png",
    "32": "images/logo.png",
    "48": "images/logo.png",
    "128": "images/logo.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*.youtube.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "main.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "storage"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://youtube.com/*"
  ]
}
```

When the event `joinRoom` emit, I can confirm that the `connect` function executes. But the code in `ws.on("connect")` doesn't run.

Connecting to `URL` using socket.io on NodeJS, Postman and in Chromium normal webpage browser console works fine.

Comment: Do it inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/).

Comment: @xOxxOm how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding `transports: ['websocket']` to `io` options:

```
io(URL, {
  transports: ["websocket"],
});
```